# Java Spring JUnit Test Datasource not specified

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public long getUniqueId() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateAndTime= dateFormat.format(new Date());
    jdbcTemplate.update(someSqlQuery, dateAndTime);

    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("IDENTITY").withReturnValue();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I want to write simple unit test but whenever the code reaches the line with `SimpleJdbcCall` throws exception that "DataSource is not specified". This is my test so far:

```
@Test
public void testGetBatchId() {
    transactionImpl.getUniqueId();
}
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: That's not a unit test, it's an integration test. Also, is your data source defined in the test scope?

Comment: There appears to be an extra '}' in your "following code" section. Is there some code missing from the code you would like to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make integration test you need the data source defined in the test scope

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = GatewayApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class ControllerIT {
```

Comment: I am using spring boot by the way :)

Comment: In that case, did you use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` ?

Comment: Only @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) Not @SpringBootTest

Comment: I am using my own extension of the Application class if that is what you mean?

Comment: Does your test know that? Have you given a reference to this in an annotation at the test? Hard to guess, without your actuall test class ;-)

Comment: With Spring Boot 1.4 I suggest switching to the mentioned SpringRunner class and the SpringBootTest annotation, btw.